# How to monitor events of process start and exit under Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, process, monitoring, events

Under Windows, we can use **Process Monitor** to monitor various activities of all processes, such as events of process start and exit.

Is there a similar tool under Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [top](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html), which is a console program and there is [KSysGuard](https://userbase.kde.org/KSysGuard) (if your desktop environment is KDE), which is a GUI program.
If you are using GNOME - they have gnome-system-monitor, which is also GUI program.
Hope that helps.